# Global javascript variable is not posting via data table ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, datatable

I'm trying to post an extra custom value to my MVC controller for my serverside data table. It seems no matter what I do though, I can't post the value I want, it always returns null in my view model. Here is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 window.searchValue;
            function updateSearchValuesBeforeSend() {
                window.searchValue = $("#searchValue").val();
                Table.fnFilter(this.value);
            }
            $("#submitButton").on('click', function (event) {
                updateSearchValuesBeforeSend();
            });
            function getAString() {
                return $("#searchValue").val();
            } 
            var Table = $('#work-order-table').dataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                scrollX: true,
                scrollResize: true,
                scrollY: 600,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                bStateSave: true,
                fnStateSave: function (oSettings, oData) {
                    localStorage.setItem('work-order-table', JSON.stringify(oData));
                },
                fnStateLoad: function (oSettings) {
                    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('work-order-table'));
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("FilterList")',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'search_value': window.searchValue
                    },
```

if I replace window.searchValue with a string like 'something', that gets posted with no issues. I've tried directly doing $("#searchValue").val() in the ajax call, doesn't work, tried doing  `${window.searchValue}`, and also creating a function that returns $("#searchValue").val() instead of storing it in a variable. When i do console.log(window.searchValue) before calling Table.fnFilter(this.value), it prints the correct value for what I have in the input, but still posts as null in my model.

EDIT: Let me reiterate that I'm looking for the value in from the input AFTER a search button is pressed, I know that the first ajax call will be null on page load.

Comment: is the search value available when the page loads?  because it looks like you've attempting to obtain the search value when a button is clicked, but the DataTable ajax call is happening on `document.ready()`.  You should be able to see and inspect what is being to sent to the controller, and when, using F12 Developer Tools, network tab

Comment: It is ready when I call Table.fnFilter() in updateSearchValuesBeforeSend(), which is starting the ajax call. I've called console.log(window.searchValue) before calling TablefnFilter() too and it prints the correct value to the console.

Comment: Did you verify using Developer Tools, Network tab, that the AJAX is firing when your call the table filter and not when the page loads?  Also, verify that `data` has the value you expect in that AJAX call you're looking at from the Network tab. I suspect this is a timing issue.

Comment: Yes, it's 100% firing, confirmed in the network tab and i'm debugging my project via visual studio and it's reaching my controller when i call the table filter. Also, as I said earlier if i do like data: { 'search_value' : 'value' } it posts the data correctly. It's only if I do anything other than a simple string that its sending null.

Comment: It makes sense if you hard code the value that it would post.  But if the field does not yet have a value on `document.ready()` (or if the field doesn't yet exist on the page), it would be posting null.  This is why I'm thinking it's a timing issue.

Comment: it's not a timing issue, the input is EMPTY on page load, it doesn't need to post any value, so of course the first call is null. I have a submit button that calls updateSearchValuesBeforeSend() and starts the ajax call AFTER the page has loaded and something has been written to the input. I am looking for the input value AFTER the button press, NOT on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by directly adding the properties I wanted to the javascript object that the data table was passing to my controller.

```
ajax: {
      url: '@Url.Action("FilterList")',
      method: 'POST',
      data: function (d) {
           d["search_value"] = $("#searchValue").val();
           d["name_value"] = $("#nameList").val();
           d["date_value"] = $("#dateValue").val();
       },
```